# How to load JSON.js library with Require JS in order to make a Backbone app work in IE7?

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, backbone.js, requirejs

I have managed to make my Backbone app work with IE8 - IE Edge... Yey:)

The last stone is IE7 - I get the following Backbone error:

```
'JSON' is undefined - file: backbone.js
```

And there is some part of the backbone library code highlighted by IE's console:

```
s.data=JSON.stringify(i.attrs||e.toJSON(i)
```

From what I read, I have to load JSON2 or JSON3 library because IE7 does not have it.

Ok, googled and go the following library - JSON 3:

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.2.6/json3.min.js
```

**Now, I use require js to load my application, and I have no idea how to integrate this with my app config.**

**What are it's dependencies, what does it export?**

Here is my config for require js:

```
/**
 *  Config.
 */

require.config({

    paths: {
        "jquery" : "libs/jquery",
        "underscore" : "libs/underscore",
        "backbone" : "libs/backbone",
        "text" : "libs/require/text",
        "global" : "libs/global",
        templates: '../templates'
    },

    shim: {

        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },

        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },

        text : {
            exports : 'text'
        }
    },

    global : {
        deps: ["jquery"],
        exports : 'Global'
    }
});

require([

    'jquery',

    'underscore',

    'backbone',

    'router',

    'global'

], function ($, _, Backbone, Router) {

    // Compatibility override, add a close function for the Backbone views.

    var router = new Router();

    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add the json library to your path config:

```
paths: {
    "json": "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.2.6/json3.min.js",
    "jquery" : "libs/jquery",
    "underscore" : "libs/underscore",
    "backbone" : "libs/backbone",
    "text" : "libs/require/text",
    "global" : "libs/global",
    templates: '../templates'
},
```

The json library has no dependencies and exports a global variable JSON. You will need to make the backbone library depend on the json library, and load the JSON library with a shim config. See below:

```
shim: {

    json: {
        exports: 'JSON'
    },

    backbone: {
        deps: ["underscore", "jquery", "json"],
        exports: "Backbone"
    },

    underscore: {
        exports: '_'
    },

    text: {
        exports: 'text'
    }
}
```